# asp.net core Identity server auth client to api to api question

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Here my question:

My window client call a secure API usign identity server 4, now the called API need to call another API that is also protected using identity server 4. My first API as it's own apiName, could this be used somehow to be sent to the second api as credential

Or i need to create a new Client ID to access the second API?

Comment: It's not clear the flow type you are using here. Is your Windows client using an interactive flow that requires user action (login form)?  Or is this strictly a client credential-based with no user-specific login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios but both of them need your first api's client ID & client secret :

1 . Delegation Flow :

A front end client calls a middle tier API using a token acquired via an interactive flow (e.g. hybrid flow). This middle tier API (API 1) now wants to call a back end API (API 2) on behalf of the interactive user . See [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant) for document and code flow .

2 .  Client Credential Flow

Your first api use its credential(client id and secret) to acquire access token for accessing the second api , no matter how you get first api's access token in client app . See [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) for document and code flow .

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes your API will need it's own client_id to access the second API.

Each client that needs to access a protected resource needs to have a unique client_id & secret.

In your example, you have 3 elements in play:
1. `Windows client`
2. `Secure API A`
3. `Secure API B`

Your `windows client` has a client_id & secret used to get a bearer token to communicate with the protected resource `Secure API A`.

`Secure API A` is both a protected resource and a client. It will need to have a client_id & secret to receive a bearer token in order to communicate with `Secure API B`.